# How to take selected value from option field in html using node.js code?

Tags: html, node.js

I am working on node.js this is new to me so i stucked here..how to take 
    selected value from option field in html using node.js

Here is my html code :

```
<select name="selectedValue" class="form-control hidden">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
   <option selected="selected">6</option>
   <option>7</option>
</select>
```

So how to get the selected option value through node.js here is my node.js
    code:

```
var _numberOfPass=req.body.selectedValue;
```

But i got the output as undefined i didn't success ed to take the selected option value from html please tell me the solution for the above problem.

Comment: Depends on what HTTP server library you are using (and possible also on how the `<form>` is set up.

Comment: Are you using `app.use(express.bodyParser());` ? ,in my opinion that's the problem , you should configure express, Btw do you send as a json or as http query parameter? can you share your full code related to your post/get route method?

Comment: yes i am using body parser..var bodyParser=require('body-parser'); and also i configured to express

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

Comment: app.post('/flightsearch',function(req,res){

var _from=req.body.from;
var _to=req.body.to;

var _departuredate=req.body.start;
var _returndate=req.body.end;


var _ToOne=req.body.toOne;
var _departuredateOne=req.body.startOne;

var _numberOfPass=req.body.selectedValue;

res.send(_from +" <br/>" + _to + " <br/>" + _departuredate + " <br/>"+_returndate + " <br/>" + _numberOfPass );

});


Under the post '/flightsearch' is the action (method="post') under the form element in html.I taken
all the field values like from,to,start date,end date,but the number of passengers value is i didn't from html